# Notice в функции date после пересборки PHP 5.2

Tags: php, дата, php5

Есть notice

> Use of undefined constant Ymd - assumed 'Ymd' .

В строке с ошибкой написано `date( Ymd, $row['date'] )`.

Я не понимаю как раньше это работало, если правильно `date( 'Ymd', $row['date'] );`

Проблема появилась после пересборки php 5.2 (пересобирал не я).

Вот вопрос, каким образом раньше работало date( Ymd, $row['date'] ), что делает его корректным? В phpinfo о date написано следующее:

```
date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2012.3
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    Europe/Helsinki

Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
```

Answer (score 2):

Use of undefined constant Ymd - assumed 'Ymd' .

переводится с аглицкого как "Использование неопределенной константы Ymd, сделано предположение, что это строка 'Ymd'."

То есть если оно не нашло такую константу, оно присваивает ей значение, равное ее имени.

Будте внимательны с константами класса такой фокус не прокатит.

Comment: Да, верно, интерпретатор считает что выражение Ymd - это константа, так как оно не взято в кавычки. Но данной константы нет, и никогда не было и не предполагалось. Вместо нее там должен быть формат даты 'Ymd'.

Comment: тогда я не вижу проблемы. Возьмите в кавычки или отключите отображение нотисов.

Comment: Проблема в том, что на сервере 100+ сайтов, и раньше это как-то работало без кавычек. Может есть какое-то дополнение к сборке php?

Answer (score 1):

Дело не в сборке, а в настройке php.ini

Только что у себя попробовал на PHP 5.2 вывести:

```
 echo date(Ymd);
```

Нормально вывел дату: `20130806`. Но на моем компьютере php.ini Настроен так, что съедает почти все ошибки возникающие с отсутствием переменных, и работает не вылетая.